# Run integration-test for Spring from IDE

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, integration-testing

I'm using the embedded-glassfish for integration tests. My web service written in jersey + spring.

I have written test for class AuthFacadeBean. When I run the tests through maven - all tests successfully passed. But when I run the test in IDE - returning NullPointerException.

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ... >   
    <context:component-scan base-package="api.facade" />
    <bean id="authService" scope="singleton" class="api.management.AuthServiceImpl" />
</beans>
```

AuthServiceImpl:

```
public interface AuthService {
    String login (String secretKey, Integer userId, String accessToken);
}
```

AuthFacadeBean:

```
@ Component
@ Scope ("request")
@ Path ("/ auth")
@ Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AuthFacadeBean {

    @ Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @ GET
    public Response auth (@ QueryParam ("secretKey") String secretKey,
                       @ QueryParam ("userId") Integer userId, @ QueryParam ("accessToken") String accessToken) {
        authService.login (secretKey, userId, accessToken); // exception in this line
        return Response.ok (). build ();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public class AuthIntegrationTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Test
    public void testAuth() {
        URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri(getEndpoint()).path("api/auth")
                .queryParam("userId", 1)
                .queryParam("accessToken", "qwe")
                .queryParam("secretKey", "secret")
                .build();
        ClientResponse response = getClient().resource(url).get(ClientResponse.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(ClientResponse.Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Stack-trace:

```
янв 21, 2013 12:35:02 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at api.facade.AuthFacadeBean.auth(AuthFacadeBean.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in pom.xml. Need to add spring-test:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you added some default profiles(such as run the embed container when start the tests) on the pom.xml even setting.xml under M2_HOME/conf and when you run the tests in IDE, the default profiles were not triggered.

Comment: No, i use default profile. I can run maven build from IDE with this profile, all tests successfully passed.